# Must a multiplicative bijection on a ring $R \rightarrow R'$ with all elements nilpotent or units be an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$f : R \rightarrow R'$ is a multiplicative bijection, i.e. for all $x,y \in R$ we have $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$, where $R$ is a ring such that every element is either a unit or nilpotent.

Must $f$ be an isomorphism?

Thoughts:

If this were to be true, it is sufficient to prove $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for any $x,y$. So it would be nice to relate the addition and multiplication operations together somehow. My first thought to obviously do this is some bracket expansion of the form

$f((x+y)^k)=(f(x+y))^k$ and relate somehow. (We know that the sum of nilpotents is nilpotent by such a bracket expansion. This leads to the nilpotents form an ideal which might be useful?).

I do not see how to proceed with this idea though. We could attempt some downwards induction on

$[f(x)+f(y)]^k = [f(x+y)]^k$

since we have a base case by nilpotence. But this seems unlikely as we do not know we are in an integral domain or inverses exist so cant cancel factors easily to reduce to $k-1$ case.

I have heard that there is a unique prime ideal in such a ring, but don't know how I can utilise this.

N.B. The original question specified *every element* was nilpotent. But then we must have $R$ is trivial ring so is clearly true. I would therefore guess they mean every non unit element?

Any ideas/hints would be appreciated!

Comment: The assumption that every element is nilpotent is fine if we don't assume the rings are unital.

Answer (score 4):

Let $R=\mathbb Z_2[x,y]/\langle x^2,xy,y^2\rangle$. Its elements are
$$
  R=\{0,x,y,x+y,1,1+x,1+y,1+x+y\}.
$$
Let $N=\{0,x,y,x+y\}$. Then $N^2=0$ and $R=N\cup(1+N)$. In particular the elements of $N$ are nilpotent, and those of $1+N$ are units.

Let $f:R\to R$ be the permutation that swaps $y,y+x$ and fixes all other elements. Note that $f(N)=N$ and $f$ is the identity on $1+N$. Then
$$
  f(ab)=f(a)f(b)
$$
for all $a,b\in R$. Indeed if $a,b\in N$ then $ab=0$ and $f(a)f(b)=0$. If $a,b\in 1+N$ then $ab\in 1+N$ and $f(ab)=ab=f(a)f(b)$. Finally if $a\in N$ and $b\in 1+N$ then $ab=a$ and $f(a)f(b)=f(a)$.

However $f$ is not additive, since
$$
  f(1+y)=1+y\neq 1+x+y=f(1)+f(y).
$$

Comment: The last element should perhaps be $1+x+y$

Comment: Ok so this example shows $f$ need not be a ring isomorphism, but here the image and preimage rings are the same, hence isomorphic. Can we see that there are rings such that this still holds but aren't isomorphic?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an example with non-isomorphic rings take
$$\begin{align*}\mathbb F_2[x]/x^2 &\to \mathbb Z/4 \\ 0 &\mapsto 0 \\ 1 &\mapsto 1 \\ x &\mapsto 2 \\ 1 + x &\mapsto 3.\end{align*}$$
I leave it to you to see that this is multiplicative, each of these rings satisfies the condition that every element is either nilpotent or a unit, and these rings are not isomorphic.